# Advantages of using multiple schemas?

Tags: database-design, postgresql, multi-tenant

We are currently developing In Java/Hibernate multiuser application with postgreSQL.And we are migrating our database to multiple schemas (one schema as one company);
Now i saw this drawback database size is getting more and more even though there the same data:before migrating there were 700MB; after roughly 2GB.

Because of this we are facing backuping/restoring problems it is taking much more than previous one.

Q:it can be avoided wasting time/space for making faster deliverability?
   Or, are we doing something wrong ?

Comment: Schema is just namespace, why is it more than doubling your DB size? Are you duplicating all the data? And if so would that not totally denormalize your DB.

Comment: i'm sure there's no duplicate data we are checked it.But there is one public schema and private schemas for each company with the same tables

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a simple test case that shows this happening to really investigate it.  We use literally over a thousand schemas to implement multiple wikis on a db server and it works pretty well.

And I wish I had a db that was only 2GB to backup nowadays.  :)

Comment: If i create 100 new empty schemas(with 312 tables), size of postgresql's data folder size increased by 1.2GB. Is this not strange?

Answer (score 1):

You have not written what you have really done.

I suppose you have some common data (f.g. dictionaries) that you have also copied. When this data will be common for each company (not customized), you should just keep it in separated schema.

Comment: Yes,We have separated public schema for storing constants, references.For one sign up(new company) will be created one private schema without data.